# Saxon C how to run multiple xslts on a cached xml

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, saxon

I want to run several Xslts with one cached xml . However I can only find ways to run several xml files with
a cachedxslt , but thats not what I want . As well as an XsltExecutable for Xslt , can there be an XsltExecutbale for Xmls, so that i can cache an xml , and run several xslts on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DocumentBuilder and use `parseXmlFromFile` (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc11/html/classDocumentBuilder.html#a4fd6acc79cbed4ae3aa9bd062ffa080f) to parse your XML input file once into an `XdmNode`, then you can feed that XdmNode as the input to any `transformTo...` method you call on your XsltExecutable or run any `applyTemplates..` method after setting that XdmNode as the initial match selection with the method `setInitialMatchSelection`.